# Sending email through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I am using the validate plugin for a form. 
I just want a contactform with no refresh. I guess it is possible.

This is my Javascript:

```
$().ready(function() {
// validate the comment form when it is submitted.

 $("#actualForm").validate({
focusInvalid: false,
onkeyup: true,
    rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
        name: "required",
        comment: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
    },

submitHandler: function(form) {   
            var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
            var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
            var comment = $('input[name="comment"]').val();
            var params = {
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "comment": comment,
            };

            console.log(data);debugger;
            $.ajax({
            url: 'email.php',
            data: params,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: json,
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.status) {
                    //Give success log to user
                } else {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
            });
        }
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$to = 'myemail';
$from = $email;
$subject = 'subject';
$body = "Hello Admin<br><br>
        Name: <strong>$name</strong><br>
        Email: $email<br>
        Bericht: $comment<br>
            ";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
$ok = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($ok)
    echo '1';
else
    echo '0';
?>
```

I also have an invalidHandler, but that thing is working so i guess it's useless to put it here.

But I am stuck for hours now and I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you try to run your php script directly without ajax?

Comment: What does it actually do? Any output, I see the console should log something?

Comment: @FredericNault no, i do not have tried that yet. 
Aurel300 It refreshed my page. And it does not send any email. That log outputs my data.

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing an important line of code to send Email in HTML `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` @Drogon

Comment: @FredericNault, i have run the email without the ajax. It sends an email with only this:  Name: <strong></strong><br>
            Email: <br>
            Bericht: <br>

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- , now it sends an email. But without any data

Comment: @Drogon, ok a leat the email get sent, so the bug is not from php... Do you know jsfiddle, could you put your code there I will be able to assist you from that

Comment: You're welcome. Your form's input elements may not be named. Do they have something to the effect of `<input type="text" name="name">` etc.? @Drogon

Comment: yes @FredericNault, here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4M23/

Comment: where the function validate is coming from?

Comment: Thats a part of the plugin. So i hoped it would be ok so. I read the documentation and the $(form).validate was like this there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have a little mistake inside the ajax function

replace:

```
dataType: json,
```

by:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Without '', json is considered as a variable name, and in your case you want to pass 'json' as a value.

Comment: I have changed it. But a wonder just happend: I do not have changed email.php and it does not send any email anymore... How is this possible

Comment: hmm on my side that was working on the jsfiddle, did you have firebug or any tool to see all ajax request/answer?

Comment: are you sure about this value : url: 'email.php'

Comment: my ajax is doing well now. Because it he reached my success function
I have put an alert and he reaches that. But if i go to email.php it returns 0. Where it first gave me 1. Yes, I am sure about the URL

Comment: Earlier we test the php directly and you said it was working fine. so I guess we have to test it again. if you replace your echo '0'; by var_dump($to, $subject, $body, $headers), we will see which variable broke the script

Comment: this is what I get: string(21) "My Email" string(7) "subject" string(60) "Hello Admin Name: Email: Bericht: " string(70) "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 MIME-Version: 1.0 From: "

Comment: look like the $to is equal to  "My Email" ? I thik you should change it to a real email

Comment: I have changed that for Stack, my right email is showing up there, which i get out $to

Comment: ok It still working without ajax? Could you try to remove that $header parameter when you use mail. If that work That will tell you that something is wrong with your header text

Comment: Ajax is working, my email not. I have removed my header and this is what i get: bool(false) string(21) "my email" string(7) "subject" string(60) "Hello Admin Name: Email: Bericht: " bool(false)

Comment: could you paste me your last php version on pastebin please

Comment: Thanks for your help frederic! My emails sends. With my PHP was nothing wrong. It was my hosting provider which was not configured right. I only get the problem with my Ajax now: http://pastebin.com/ZebFRScM
It always returns an error, but my email is send though

Answer (score 0):

I have a tendency to use var_dump to debug.

What's var_dump($_POST); giving you?

Do you get a 500 network response in your browser?

Type console.log(data); in your success function too. That will give you a hint on how to solve the problem.